# Prevent Visual Studio from encrypting files

Tags: visual-studio, encryption

I was just shocked when I saw this dialog popping up, because I thought I was a victim of an encryption virus:

[image: Backup encryption key]

Using Process Explorer to see which process opened the dialog, I found `efsui.exe` and I verified the signature to make sure it was an official Microsoft product.

Next, I googled about this and I found the command `cipher /u` to find encrypted files on my disk. The result was

```
C:\Windows\system32>cipher /u
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Backup Files\Form1.Designer.vb\~AutoRecover.Form1.Designer.vb.sln: Encryption updated.
```

and that's confirmed when opening the folder in Explorer.

[image: Encryption in Windows Explorer]

I'm using Visual Studio for a long time, but it's the first time I opened a VB Form.

Is it common that Visual Studio encrypts files? Does it only happen for VB or is this due to some other VS update that was installed recelty? How to turn that feature off?

I tried:

- enter "encrypt" and "encryption" in Visual Studio's quick find box.
- finding an answer like [this one about removable drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726333/how-to-turn-off-encrypting-of-sln-files-in-visual-studio-on-removable-drive) but my drive is C: and not removable.

Comment: Huh, the very same thing has just happened to me, VS has arbitrarily decided to encrypt a single AutoRecover file, prompting windows to ask me to backup my certificate and keys - that's hilarious.

Comment: I just spent half an hour searching for "Export Certificate Wizard unexpectedly appears" and only found this answer after solving it myself using the same steps. Commenting so that other people looking at the Export Certificate Wizard window have a chance to find this answer. That was a scary half hour, too -- I thought I'd gotten ransomware! Dammit, Visual Studio, warn me before you do that!

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is a feature that project templates/extensions can enable:

> From: http://www.visualmicro.com/forums/YaBB.pl?num=1362001590/0
>
> > In summary, a number of machinations of Win32 code produced .sln recovery files, none encrypted.  A creation of an independent arduino project created an encrypted .sln recovery file within a a minute or so

In this case the Arduino template seems to have this particular flag (perhaps because it can store credentials (App Store IDs, private keys etc.)).

In my mind it's an excellent sign that Microsoft Visual Studio devs have thought of the possibility of leaking sensitive/confidential information in the "temporary" files that might even go roaming via the domain controller and profile replication.

As such, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable the feature (and rightly so). But you can always store your projects/application data on a filesystem that doesn't support NTFS encryption. As the name implies, this would likely be any other filesystem.¹

---

¹ it's not impossible that any POSIX filesystems supporting extended attributes could also support this feature on Windows, but I haven't heard of it before

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Visual Studio (e.g.: 2019) still do this, and in my case, it decided to encrypt a backup of a single icon file. There wasn't even a project open, it just decided to do this all on its own for no apparent reason. I'd definitely classify this as a bug.

What I ended up doing is disabling EFS altogether, since I don't need VS deciding to encrypt files whenever it gets the urge. You can do this using the Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc) and select Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > File System > NTFS and enable the "Do not allow encryption on all NTFS volumes".

Important note: If you decide to do this, make sure you decrypt any encrypted files using the **cipher /d** command before you disable EFS. Otherwise, you won't be able to decrypt them.